# Package libsndfile-dev has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, apt-get, libsndfile

I am trying to install "libsndfile-dev". I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev
```

As the result I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsndfile-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libsndfile1-dev 1.0.17-4ubuntu0.8.10.2
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libsndfile-dev has no installation candidate
```

So, my attempt to install failed. Can anybody tell me what should I select explicitly and how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you should `apt-get install libsndfile1-dev`  (note the 1).